# Cordova missing permissions Windows Phone and Android

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to build an applicatie using Cordova to build it for Windows Phone 8+ and Android 4+. Now when I try to load an image from an external source I get the following error for Windows Phone

> SEC7117: Network request to http://fundatie.ruben.dnz/CmsData/Artikelen/Fotos/1/0/100006/100006_main_800x800_1.jpg did not succeed.
>   Your application manifest does not declare the following capabilities: internetClient privateNetworkClientServer

How do I declare these capabilities for Windows Phone?

I am using Cordova 5.1.1 in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. My layout is from the Ionic sidemenu template.

My application
[Application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8XAW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preference in your config.xml file:

```
<widget>
<preference ... />
```

Also, if you'll check your project directory after building the project to your destination platform - for instance :

```
...\bin\Windows Phone (Universal)\Release
```

You will see there the auto generated manifests, if you'll the manifest to :

```
../res/native/windows
```

This will override some of the properties of the auto generated manifest file by config.xml.
so you can try this approach.
Anyway, do check the auto generated manifest if you set up the internet permission.

That's how I make my platform specific changes in Cordova projects.

Comment: When I copy the manifest from `...\bin\Windows Phone (Universal)\Release` to `../res/native/windows` and add the capabilities. It does not take these changes into account when I build the project

Comment: Check that your CPU architecture is set to ARM and that you are coping the Phone manifest. Is your project windows phone or Universal app?

Comment: My project is a Universal app. But where do I check that the CPU is set to ARM?

Comment: Near the F5 (green button  - play) which you click for running the app, there is a combo box with platform selection, you can choose there Windows Phone 8/ Windows Phone (universal) and such... If you run on phone it has to be ARM...

Comment: I see. But at the moment I do not have a Windows Phone device so I am stuck with the emulator for the moment.

Comment: I think that if you run the app on Windows Phone Emulator as Windows Phone Universal app it should take the Windows Phone Manifest anyway. Also I think I forgot, you should copy the package.windows.appxmanifestfile as well - Try that.

Comment: You are the best! I indeed fogot the `package.windows.appxmanifest` it now works like a charm! Thanks alot